# how to convert Final_Unique column into a header values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

[sample image to check the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQZMc.png)

**SAMPLE DATA**

```
Actual_Data     Final_Unique
8,8,8,8,8,8,        8,8
6,7,7,7,6,7,        6,7
2,12,3,4,12,12,     7,7
14,14,14,14,14,14,  7,6
1,1,12,2,2,4,       2,12
6,8,8,8,8,12,       12,3
6,6,6,6,3,14,       3,4
1,14,14,1,1,2,      4,12
1,1,1,1,1,14,       12,12
```

i am trying this

newdf = a.pivot(index='Actual_Data', columns='Final_Unique')

i have 2 column actual data and final_unique column in actual i have 44000 rows and final_unique has 266 rows i want to get the 266 column and actual data to stay same as it and count how many time actual data appears in the header

error getting

duplicate data exist can't reshape

**output expected**

```
ACTUAL DATA          8,8  6,7  7,7   7,6  2,12

8,8,8,8,8,8,          3   0    0      0    0

6,7,7,7,6,7,          0    2    1     1    0

2,12,3,4,12,12,       0    0    0     0    1
```

Comment: If you give the input data as text so that I can copy and paste it, I could try to answer. You should read [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: ??? i didn't got you

Comment: You have only given an **image** of your input. Please put it directly as text in the question itself. I am much too lazy to write it by hand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pivot_table` allows an aggregate function, so if you only add on column containing `1` to you dataframe, you could get the expected result:

```
newdf = a.assign(val=1).pivot_table(values='val', index='Actual_Data',
                                    columns='Final_Unique', aggfunc=sum, fill_value=0
                                    ).reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

With the sample data it gives:

```
          Actual_Data  12,12  12,3  2,12  3,4  4,12  6,7  7,6  7,7  8,8
0       1,1,1,1,1,14,      1     0     0    0     0    0    0    0    0
1       1,1,12,2,2,4,      0     0     1    0     0    0    0    0    0
2      1,14,14,1,1,2,      0     0     0    0     1    0    0    0    0
3  14,14,14,14,14,14,      0     0     0    0     0    0    1    0    0
4     2,12,3,4,12,12,      0     0     0    0     0    0    0    1    0
5       6,6,6,6,3,14,      0     0     0    1     0    0    0    0    0
6        6,7,7,7,6,7,      0     0     0    0     0    1    0    0    0
7       6,8,8,8,8,12,      0     1     0    0     0    0    0    0    0
8        8,8,8,8,8,8,      0     0     0    0     0    0    0    0    1
```

---

From you comments, the two columns of the original `a` dataframe are not directly related but are in fact two independant Series, and you just want to know how many times a `Final_Unique` value occurs in a `Actual_Data` one.

This code should give it:

```
newdf = a[['Actual_Data']]
for col in set(a['Final_Unique'].dropna()):
    newdf[col] = newdf.Actual_Data.str.findall('(^|,)'+col+'(?=,)').apply(len)
```

The result is:

```
          Actual_Data  8,8  12,3  12,12  7,7  2,12  6,7  4,12  3,4  7,6
0        8,8,8,8,8,8,    3     0      0    0     0    0     0    0    0
1        6,7,7,7,6,7,    0     0      0    1     0    2     0    0    1
2     2,12,3,4,12,12,    0     1      1    0     2    0     1    1    0
3  14,14,14,14,14,14,    0     0      0    0     0    0     0    0    0
4       1,1,12,2,2,4,    0     0      0    0     0    0     0    0    0
5       6,8,8,8,8,12,    2     0      0    0     0    0     0    0    0
6       6,6,6,6,3,14,    0     0      0    0     0    0     0    0    0
7      1,14,14,1,1,2,    0     0      0    0     0    0     0    0    0
8       1,1,1,1,1,14,    0     0      0    0     0    0     0    0    0
```

The rationale behind the above code is:

- compute the list of columns from the `Final_Unique` columns: the `set` will automatically remove duplicates (but will break order) and `dropna()` will remove empty values
- create a new dataframe from the `Actual_Data` column.
- add columns to that dataframe from the list computed at previous step and for each column

  - use `str.findall` and an appropriate regex to find non overlapping sequence containing the column name after a comma or at beginning of string and followed  by a comma - that last comma not being included in the matched string to allow consecutive sequences to be correctly counted, hence the `(?=...)`
  - apply the len function to tranform that list in a simple count

Comment: you didnt understand the question , i just want to get the final unique column to be header and then find 8,8  6,7  7,7   7,6  2,12(as they are in column now then in actual_data column i want to check how many time  8,8  6,7  7,7   7,6  2,12
 appears traversing each row)

Comment: @Quicklearner: this is the reason why it is important to give some data with the associated output. As I could not imagine how the *expected* output was related to the sample data, I have just tried what I had understood...

Comment: did you understand now ?

Comment: @Quicklearner: I have not understood more, and I am afraid I will not unless you show the **exact** output expected for the sample data... I would be glad to help you, but you should also help me to help you :-)

Comment: 1,1,1,1,1,14,  in this there no  12,12 still its mark 1 i have to find 12,12 appeared in this row or not , same for other check how many times 12,3 appear , 2,12 appeared  in all the actual data column

Comment: Ok, I think I begin to understand. But how do you count only 1 `8,8` in `8,8,8,8,8,8,`? I would expect 3...

Comment: i changed it i got it by mistake its 3 only

Comment: Serge Ballesta : is there anything you got

Comment: why i am not getting in actual order it were in final_unique column ? also can you explain what you did?

Comment: 14,14,14,14,14,14, 0 5 0 3 @Serge Ballesta  its giving 5 for 1,4 which is wrong here , it should give only 3 for 14,14

Comment: @Quicklearner: you have said that the `Final_Unique` column had only 266 values. But all columns in a dataframe have the exact same number of rows. So I assumed that the column could contain duplicates or NaN values and used a set to remove duplicates (but it also breaks order) and `dropna()` to remove NaN. If you had described you data in a non ambiguous way, I should not have to guess...

Comment: For the line 14.14.14.14.14.14, could you share a data sample exhibiting the problem? I need a [mcve] to reproduce the problems. The SO rules goal is not to bore askers but to make sure that answers are relevant and addresses all the problems.

Comment: I am really very sorry for this I don’t know stackoverflow well to write a gud question I apologise for this

Comment: @Quicklearner: That's the reason why I tell you it and give you those 2 links. You should also read [ask] if you have not before. That way your next question will be nicer... BTW we all used to be beginners :-)

Comment: i have updated the output i am getting from the code  & thanks alot for your help here – Serge Ballesta

Comment: @Quicklearner: I have reverted your edit because it did not make sense in the middle of my answer. But it was quite relevant and I think I have seen where the problem comes from. I should post an edit soon...

Comment: @Quicklearner: I could reproduce and fix. Please see my edit. For the column order, if you are sure that no duplicates exist, just remove the `set`: `for col in a['Final_Unique'].dropna():`

Comment: Thanks alot  for the help also can you please explain what you did here, its working fine, i am new here how can get your help regularly :)  – Serge Ballesta

Comment: I am getting an error while performing k- means clustering ok data set of can’t convert string to float or int

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

```
import re
l1 = list(a['Actual_Data'])
l2 = list(a['Final_Unique'])
d = {i: [len(re.findall(i,j)) for j in l1] for i in l2}
newdf = pd.DataFrame(d,index=l1)
```

if you have an issue with data types:

```
import re
l1 = list(a['Actual_Data'])
l2 = list(a['Final_Unique'])
d = {i: [len(re.findall(str(i),str(j))) for j in l1] for i in l2}
newdf = pd.DataFrame(d,index=l1)
```

What I've done here is forced every value of Actual_Data and Final_Unqiue into a string.

Comment: what is re here ?
d = {i: [len(re.findall(i,j)) for j in l1] for i in l2}

Comment: re is regex, a package for regular expressions matching

Comment: Error ; 
first argument must be string or compiled pattern

Comment: i am counting 3 here as i am matching the pair 8,8 to rest

Comment: This error means one of your 'Final_Unique' patterns isn't a `string`. I've modified it above

Comment: its running from last  mins :)

Comment: its not i got waiting and star on my jupter notebook

Comment: i also have to make Final_Unique column as column header  to put the  output under them

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your issue - what do you need? Edit your question to add these issues.